# Why does my code spool infinite pages when printing in landscape mode using C#?

Tags: c#, printing, graphics

I have a peculiar situation when trying to print using the `PrintDialog`, `PrintDocument`, and `PrintPageEventHandler` classes to print documents using C#.

Whenever I print a string of text in landscape mode, my application starts spooling an infinite number of pages and will not stop until I stop debugging the application.

The following is the code corresponding to clicking on my "Print" button.

```
private void button_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument myPrintDocument = new PrintDocument();

    // assign the print document
    myPrintDialog.Document = myPrintDocument;

    // prompt the user with the dialog
    if (myPrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StringReader myStringReader = new StringReader(this.rtb_results.Text);
        myPrintDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(myPrintDocument_PrintPage);
        myPrintDocument.Print();
    }
}
```

Then, here is the code that corresponds to the "Print Page Event"...

```
void myPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    StringReader myStringReader = null;
    SolidBrush mySolidBrush = null;
    String line = String.Empty;
    Font myFont = null;
    float linesPerPage = 0;
    float leftMargin = 0;
    float topMargin = 0;
    float yPosition = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // assign the string-reader
    myStringReader = new StringReader(this.rtb_results.Text);

    // assign the brush type
    mySolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // assign the font
    myFont = new Font("Consolas", 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular);

    // assign the left margin
    leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;

    // assign the top margin
    topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;

    // assign the number of lines per page
    linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / myFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

    while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = myStringReader.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        yPosition = topMargin + (count * myFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(line, myFont, mySolidBrush, leftMargin, yPosition, new StringFormat());
        count++;
    }

    if (line != null)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }

    // not sure why this would be here...
    mySolidBrush.Dispose();
}
```

My guess at why this odd behavior might be happening, would be that there doesn't seem to be anything limiting the right-side margin (but that's just my guess). I have tried to use the `RectangleF` object to test out this theory, but I got the same results... Please let me know what I am doing wrong, if there are any questions let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you must be returning HasMorePages as true, so every time your myPrintDocument_PrintPage is called you're restarting all the process and begins at the start, you must store the position of the streamreader to seek to it again when the function is called again

Comment: @Gusman Why does this work for portrait then?

Comment: Because it fits in one page and you don't set HasMorePages to true, that's my guess..

Comment: @Gusman How do I keep track of the StreamReader position? Is there a recommended algorithm or way of doing this?

Comment: Well, you have a lot of ways, but the easiest is not to create the stream each time, prepare the stream as a gobal variable when you start printing and use it until you finish, when you finish close, dispose and set it to null, in this way you don't have to care on setting the position each time.

Comment: @Gusman How am I not doing that? The StreamReader is local to the function, and it is only called in the while loop, then disposed when I exit my function. I am not calling the "Print" function but more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're recreating the streamreader each time, so the process is restarted if the document has more than one page. What you need to do is to use the same streamreader each time.

Here is an example:

```
public Form1 : Form
{
    StringReader srPrint;

    public void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        srPrint = new StringReader(this.rtb_results.Text);
        //DO all your normal stuff to start the print
    }

    void myPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        StringReader myStringReader = null;
        SolidBrush mySolidBrush = null;
        String line = String.Empty;
        Font myFont = null;
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float leftMargin = 0;
        float topMargin = 0;
        float yPosition = 0;
        int count = 0;

        // assign the brush type
        mySolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        // assign the font
        myFont = new Font("Consolas", 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular);

        // assign the left margin
        leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;

        // assign the top margin
        topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;

        // assign the number of lines per page
        linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / myFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = srPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPosition = topMargin + (count * myFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(line, myFont, mySolidBrush, leftMargin, yPosition, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }

        if (line != null)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            srPrint.Close();
            srPrint.Dispose();
            srPrint = null;
        }

        mySolidBrush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess my issue comes from lack of understanding StreamReader... So you assign the StringReader to the global StreamReader, and that makes all the difference? I saw the way I did it as being basically the same... Except making the StreamReader global...

Comment: Isn't the StreamReader in my version considered "not - local" to the while loop that's calling/using it?

Comment: Nope, there's a big difference, each time you entered your function ou created a new stream, thus it starts at position 0, but if you create it globally JUST ONCE then the position is preserved between calls as the object is the same

Comment: It's not local to the loop but local to the function, when you exit the function it ceases existing, so if the function is called more than once more than one stream is created.

Comment: I think I see... And then you close/dispose/null at the end in order to ensure that the next print will work properly (from the beginning of the Stream)? Only thing I still don't understand is the fact that you keep saying it's called "more than once", and sorry I don't have the chat option or else I wouldn't overload your answer with comments.

Comment: Np. Yes, I say "more than once", each time you set *e.HasMorePages = true*, the system will call that event handler again, that's the mechanism to create a document with more than one page, it will be called again and again until you set *e.HasMorePages = false;*.

Comment: I get a syntax error on trying to assign the StringReader to the StreamReader.

Comment: Whooops, my mistake, change StreamReader to StringReader